# Maven/Jitpack Multi-Module project permission denied

Tags: java, maven, github, jitpack

I have set up a multi-module project [Here](https://github.com/Schottky-spi/Zener). It looks like the sample multi-module project from Jitpack. However, I cannot download single modules via maven, only the whole project. In other words, this works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.Schottky-spi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Zener</artifactId>
    <version>v3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but this doesn't

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.Schottky-spi.Zener</groupId>
    <artifactId>zener-language</artifactId>
    <version>v1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Maybe an error in the pom?
I can build and depend on any dependency locally, but others can't use it
All help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the https://github.com/Schottky-spi/Zener/packages it shows that the `zener-language` has a different version then the rest... furthermore it shows that using different version for parts of a multi module build is wrong. Furthermore I would recommend that the maintainers should use a real version number and not prefixed by `v...`... something like `1.3.1` instead..